# Laravel 5 append anchor links for pagination numbers

Tags: laravel-5, pagination

How can I append a #something to the end of the page number.

For example, this is what I want:

From:

```
abc.com/xxx/?page=2
```

To:

```
abc.com/xxx/?page=2#my-anchor
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can read about pagination in the docs here; [Laravel Pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination#displaying-pagination-results).

What you are looking for is `->fragment('my-anchor')`.

Assuming you are using eloquent,

```
$links = App\YourModel::paginate(15)->fragment('my-anchor')->links();
```